# Understanding Rails singular and plural paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm very new to using Rails and at the moment am building an Instagram clone as a project to help me understand Rails a bit better. I am following this very helpful tutorial on how to implement the likes/unlikes feature:

https://medium.com/full-taxx/how-to-add-likes-to-posts-in-rails-e81430101bc2

However, I don't fully understand the Rails paths - please could someone explain the difference between:

`post_like_path` and `post_likes_path` as mentioned in the tutorial. I cannot see why one is like and one is likes? :(

Really trying to get my head around this so would be so grateful for any insight!

Thanks :)

Comment: `post_like_path` routes by default to `posts#show` action (and you must provide post id to make it work) while `posts_like` routes to `posts#index`.

Comment: Please go through https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rails as per the REST -

1. If trying to refer to the single resource then use `post_like_path`.
2. If trying to refer to a collection of resources then use `post_likes_path`

When you want to `show` or `delete` a particular resource then you will have to provide an `:id` for the resource so that the target resource can be found.

[/posts/1/likes/1] - A single record of "like" is being referred here.

While in case of all records plural path is formed to refer to all like records -

[/posts/1/likes] - All records of "like" are being referred here.

Answer (score 0):

post model can have multiple likes. But when we do undo like it will be singular right. so `post_like_path` will handle the single like and it's going to trigger "delete" action in controller.

`post_likes_path` will trigger the new action for for creating new like.

Please routes **resources** concept then you come to know more about it.

Answer (score 0):

post_like_path is used for show page, update and destroy path. The post_likes_path will give you the path for the index and create actions.

This link is the ROR guide and has quite a simple explanation on it:

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to always run this command from terminal:

```
rake routes
```

Or just for `LikesController`:

```
rake routes -c likes
```

This shows **all the routes related to likes controllers**. That's the output, it tells a lot of things. You can see where the plural and singular is used.

```
#         Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                              Controller#Action
#     post_likes GET    /posts/:post_id/likes(.:format)          likes#index
#                POST   /posts/:post_id/likes(.:format)          likes#create
#  new_post_like GET    /posts/:post_id/likes/new(.:format)      likes#new
# edit_post_like GET    /posts/:post_id/likes/:id/edit(.:format) likes#edit
#      post_like GET    /posts/:post_id/likes/:id(.:format)      likes#show
#                PATCH  /posts/:post_id/likes/:id(.:format)      likes#update
#                PUT    /posts/:post_id/likes/:id(.:format)      likes#update
#                DELETE /posts/:post_id/likes/:id(.:format)      likes#destroy
```

First column shows you the path, the second the pattern (with required parameters) and the third the controller with action (related to the view).

**So, for example, take**

```
# new_post_like GET    /posts/:post_id/likes/new(.:format)      likes#new
```

This says that the form for a new like can be placed to a page linked by this URL:
`new_post_like_path(post_id: @post)` note the parameter required. The page is `views/likes/new.html.erb`.
the controller is `LikesController` and the action is `def new; end` where you need to instantiate the objects to be used in that page: `@like = Like.new` and `@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])`.

The form is then submitted by POST action, so the line to check is the following:

```
# post_likes POST   /posts/:post_id/likes(.:format)          likes#create
```

As before, the page where the form is located is `views/likes/new.html.erb`, the url to submit the form is `post_likes_path(post.id)`. The POST action when submitting the form is processed by the controller `LikesController` and the action is `def create; end`

**Other example:**

```
# post_like GET    /posts/:post_id/likes/:id(.:format)      likes#show
```

It tells that to show the `Like` object with a certain `id`, you need to visit this `link_to`: `post_like_path(post.id, like.id)`, the controller is `LikesController`, the action is `def show; end` and the view is in `views/likes/show.html.erb`.

And so on..